# Correct handling of ASP.NET-pages when scraping

Tags: asp.net, screen-scraping

I am scraping a certain ASP.NET-enabled search page from a Python script and running into trouble getting the data I want from postbacks.

So I want to verify if I've got ASP.NET related bits correctly before ruling it out.

So far I just take all hidden form variables (e.g. `__VIEWSTATE`) and send them with other POST request parameters. **Is this correct or they should change in some way?** POST response contains updated hidden variables, which I assume should become parameters of the next postback, however when I browse the same page in Firefox, not all hidden form fields posted back are the same (e.g. `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT`).

**Do I need any other special handling here or this is all there is to it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty much all there is to it.  The main thing is maintaining __VIEWSTATE from one post to another; which it sounds like you've covered.

Comment: I take it the client cannot change __VIEWSTATE?

Comment: @Alex B: View state is the "encrypted" state of the page as it was delivered to the client.  This information is decrypted by the server on post back and compared to various values.  If something is remiss, then you get a nice yellow screen complaining about viewstate.  So, no, the client cannot change it.